# New car first service due in date not in KM

Tags: service, warranty

I recently purchased a "new" subaru outback diesel with 20km on it. Now a month passed and I put 600km on it. However, the 1st service is overdue in time (in fact the first serives was due 1 week after my pick up of the car according to the sticker) but not in km (12500km). I don't want to take it for service until at least another 5 months. My question is, does this harm or void any part of the factory warranty? 
Thanks. I'm in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

The « first service » you mention is usually after a short period of time as they will check / replace fluids like engine oil.

This is sometimes because the engine oil can be a « running - in » grade for the first use if the vehicle and needs changing after a week as you say.

Phone them and get it done : it may affect the warranty if you don’t
Also, it may be a free one anyway - does depend on the manufacturer though...

Comment: I agree it might be a free service, in fact the dealer *should* have done it before they gave it to you.

Comment: @GdD there is a difference between a pdi ( pre delivery inspection) and a first service.

Comment: True @SolarMike, I'm assuming that the OP bought the car from a dealer, in which case they should have done it from a reputation point of view, not that it was an actual requirement. At least they should have mentioned it and what to do. It's just good business.